# Apply two CSS classes which contain `filter` to an HTML element

Tags: html, css

For example, I want to apply both `aaa` and `bbb` to an element, but it seems that only one works at a time. `class="aaa bbb"` did not work. How to do it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .aaa
        {
            filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px black);
        }

        .bbb
        {
            filter: grayscale(100%);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"
        class="aaa bbb"
        style="margin:40px" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: only one filter css property can be applied so if you want to do both drop-shadow and grayscale it needs to be on the same filter rule:
filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px black) grayscale(100%)

Comment: I need both `aaa` and `aaa` + `bbb` (but not `bbb` alone). Is there any way to make `bbb` inherit `aaa`? Or do I have to add `aaa`'s part to `bbb` manually?

Comment: unfortunately there is no way for it to inherit in the way you want and you will need to copy to bbb to include the full filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bbb filter` override `.aaa filter`. This is the way CSS works, it's override precedent attributes.
If you want to apply both filter, use one class with:

```
.aaa {
    filter: grayscale(100%) drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px black);
}
```